# Auditd on Ubuntu 18.04 Container

Tags: lxc, lxd, container

i want to ask something about auditd in container, here we go

recently i try install auditd in my server (outside container) and it worked i follow this steps (https://documentation.wazuh.com/3.13/learning-wazuh/audit-commands.html)
but when i try to install auditd inside my container (LXD) it's not working, i
try looking for the answer in google but they say that container does not
yet support auditd in container, can anyone confirm this?
And if anyone have trick to bypass this, it will be huge help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

auditd doesn't work in docker currently, check this: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-February/msg00011.html.

Maybe you could use volumes in docker and, by installing a Wazuh agent in the Docker host, monitoring the files that you want, assuming that you want audit for obtaining FIM who data.

Edit: I re-edit again. auditd is a daemon name, it can't start by uppercase. That's why I didn't approve your revision @Shree